# Group Average Player Count by Hour

Tags: mysql

I would like to gather the averages for `player-count` for each hour of the day so we can get a general idea of when players are most on.  The data is stored in a MySQL data.

My table is as follows:

```
id   |   datetime               |  player-count  | players
1    |   2023-11-10 23:10:05    |    32          | [{jsondata}]
1    |   2023-11-10 23:15:02    |    10          | [{jsondata}]
1    |   2023-11-10 23:20:05    |    25          | [{jsondata}]
1    |   2023-11-10 23:25:02    |    9           | [{jsondata}]
1    |   2023-11-10 23:30:01    |    3           | [{jsondata}]
```

I am unsure of how to construct the MySQL query.  I tried something along

```
SELECT *,AVG(`player-count`) AS average from `".$db->prefix."server_player_count` GROUP BY CAST(`datetime` as DATE), DATEPART(Hour, StartDate) ORDER BY CAST(`datetime` as DATE) ASC;");
```

But doesn't seem to work.  Anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Any particular reason for not sharing the exact error message or describing the unexpected behaviour? You also did nit share what the expected output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(`datetime`) AS `date`,
  HOUR(`datetime`) AS `hour`,
  AVG(`player-count`) AS `average` 
FROM `server_player_count` 
GROUP BY `date`, `hour` 
ORDER BY `date` ASC, `hour` ASC;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99d103/1

It looks very much like what you suggested, so what went wrong? Why did you ask the question?

Comment: I didn't want it ordered or grouped by day... just grouped by hours and I couldn't figure it all out.  Thankfully I was able to figure it out by your example and fiddle!!  Thank you kindly!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,avg(player_count) from table group by hour,date
```

so here you are not adding rest of the columns in group by condition as you are mentioning * in select statement. so this is throwing error(this is my assumption)

below is the query which will work to get the player_count day and hour wise

```
**SELECT 
  AVG([player-count]) AS average,DATEPART(Hour, [datetime]) as hour,CAST([datetime] as DATE) as date from [server_player_count]
  GROUP BY CAST([datetime] as DATE), DATEPART(Hour, [datetime]) ORDER BY CAST([datetime] as DATE) ASC;**
```